# Alternative Datetime.Now with only time (21:10)

Tags: c#, datetime

I was wondering if there's a method or anything which will provide me the current systemtime without the date. I need to use this in a formula and if i want to use the `DateTime.Now`I have to `String.Split` this `string` before I can convert this to a `Int`.

example: It's 5pm

**I want**:

```
'17:00', '5:00', '1700', '500'
```

**Not**:

```
'17:00 PM 29/03/2013'
```

Comment: [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) is a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y.aspx) object so you can use any of the available methods to format it.

Answer (score 7):

A DateTime holds the hour and minutes as properties.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var minutes = now.Minute;
var hours = now.Hour;
```

Comment: This. His ultimate goal is to convert this data to an integer. Anything that produces a string first is sub-optimal.

Answer (score 4):

why cannot you simply format your date i.e.

```
 string CurrentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ttt");
```

Comment: No need: he wants an integer, and he can get that directly.

Comment: exactly, he can get hours, minutes, seconds individually, but anyway he doesn't need to perform string split. he should know all the various possibilities:)

Comment: Yep exactly, the more possibilities, the better !

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is how to format a `DateTime` correctly.
Look [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) for how this is done.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `TimeOfDay`. Basically **it extracts the time part of a `DateTime`**:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan time = now.TimeOfDay;
```

Do note that unlike the `DateTime.Date` property, `DateTime.TimeOfDay` returns a `Timespan`, not a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DateTime.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; // Suppose it is currently 5pm

dt.ToString("HH:mm"); // 17:00 
dt.ToString("h:mm"); // 5:00 
dt.ToString("HHmm"); // 1700 
dt.ToString("hmm"); // 500
```

Answer (score 0):

for "1700" :

```
date.ToString('HHMM');
```

Comment: Maby this method beats them all since i need to calculate "17:56" - "13:36" :D